# Catch calling of the existing methods

Tags: php, call, traits, magic-methods

I have a class, which involves traits:

```
class Dynamic
{
   use Trait1, Trait2;

   public function method3(){};
}
```

So I need, when i'm trying to use this class like

```
$obj = new Dynamic(); 
$obj->getName(); // method from the Trait1
```

get some notifications that methods from the trait were called.

Can you advice some method for this task?

Comment: try this: `$obj->bldaiwhdolawidhaisd123('you see ;-)');` ---- will output `Calling bldaiwhdolawidhaisd123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems expected, no?

> __call() is triggered when invoking ***inaccessible*** methods in an object context.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: I'm really get down, need some rest (:
Can you advice some method to get calling of existing methods?